# Search for "id" and return all the relevant information

Tags: javascript, node.js, text

I have a log file called `test.log` (for demo purposes - which I have simplified by a lot!) which looks like this:

```
2016-16-03 16:23:22,030 INFO [session] RESPONSE {api=GetSession, URL="http://testing/123ab-1234-abc/123ab-1234-abc.m3u8"}

2016-16-03 16:23:23,879 INFO [session] RESPONSE {api=KeepAlive, Ip=11.1.111.11, result=success}

2016-16-03 16:23:23,879 INFO [info] REQUEST {httpMethod=PUT,result=false}
```

I have a simple web UI which has an "ID" field, and a search button. 
So If the user searches for `ID = 123-ab-123-abc`

They front end UI will return this log event (as it contains the ID they are looking for):

```
2016-16-03 16:23:22,030 INFO [session] RESPONSE {api=GetSession, URL="http://testing/123ab-1234-abc/123ab-1234-abc.m3u8"}
```

This may seem like a simple concept, however I am not sure how to achieve this using `Node.js` - how do I search the log file and return the whole log event which contains that specific ID/string the user inputted?

**I have tried:**

1. transforming the log file into a json object, however that did not work as some numbers would end up as string, and some parts of the log file would loose their values.
2. Separating the log file into separate String values- as every event starts from a date - and then just returning the whoel string which contains the ID - however code wise I did not get far with this option

Any other ideas/ tips on how to achieve this?

Comment: Is there a type on `123-ab-123-abc` which should be `123-ab-1234-abc`? Or you want a wildcard search?

Comment: no I just used that as an example - what do you mean by wildcard?